# Im getting an error as try' without 'catch', 'finally' or resource declarations , how can I resolve this in my below code

Tags: java

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try 
        {
            int i= Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            System.out.println(i);
            }
        System.out.println("Wipro");
        catch(NumberFormatException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't insert `System.out.println("Wipro")` between the `try` and the `catch`. It should presumably be in the `try`. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println("Wipro");
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```